# Execute a single Test Method with Ant and Junit

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, junit

I am looking for a way to run single Junit test methods (not the whole test, just a single one provided through the "-D" parameter to ant) in a Jenkins compliant way. There are a lot of different tutorials (most of them going into completely different directions) and I could not find one actually working with Junit4.*. (e.g. there is no TestCase(String methodName) constructor anymore...)

I am able to parse parameters with the "-D" option through ant and I can start single testcases with

```
Request requestCase = Request.method(Class.forName("testmethod"), Parameter.testCase);
Result result = new JUnitCore().run(requestCase);
```

but probably since I am usually running everything in TestSuites, Jenkins runs the single test seperately but doesn't register the tests have been run.

tl;dr: Is there a good way to run a single test method (not a whole class) with junit, so that Jenkins can properly pick up the results?

Answer (score 1):

That code does not generate `xml` result file that Jenkin's junit plugin usually use to publish results. It's possible to do that with an [AntXmlRunListener](https://github.com/barrypitman/JUnitXmlFormatter/blob/master/src/main/java/barrypitman/junitXmlFormatter/AntXmlRunListener.java)

```
AntXmlRunListener xmlListener = new AntXmlRunListener();
FileOutputStream reportStream = new FileOutputStream(reportDir + "/TEST-" + className + ".xml");
xmlListener.setOutputStream(reportStream);

JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.addListener(xmlListener);

// ...
// junit.run(requestCase);

xmlListener.setOutputStream(null);
reportStream.close();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411163/how-to-generate-html-report-if-my-junit-is-not-run-by-ant-but-by-junitcore-run) you will find other answers with similar approach used.

Test it locally, it should generate an `xml` file with result.

Now in your Jenkins job you need to add post build action `Publish junit results` with an appropriate regexp(something like this `**/TEST-*.xml`) to capture results.

Comment: Thanks for your efford and the quick answer! We figured out our Problem and were able to properly use Junit + Ant + Jenkins. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, we found a properly working solution using reflections:
In the Junit suite()-method:

```
if (Parameter.testCase != null){  //Parameter contains all parsed parameters
        try {

            Class<?> classGen = Class.forName("package.path" + Parameter.testPlatform.toString());

            Constructor<?> constructor =
                    classGen.getConstructor( new Class[] { String.class } );

            suite.addTest( (Test) constructor.
                    newInstance( new Object[] { Parameter.testCase } ) );
            return suite;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Logger.log("ERROR: Error executing single test" + Parameter.testCase);
            e.printStackTrace(); //the output is actually logged properly
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

For this to work, every Testclass needs to extend junit.framework.TestCase